# Mcrypt PHP exention missing! Erro ao instalar aplicação

Tags: php, xampp

Boa noite amigos, estou tentando rodar uma aplicação php local, mas esta dando erro
**Mcrypt PHP exention missing!
Mysql PHP exention missing!**

Já tirei o ; do **extension=php_intl.dll** mas mesmo assim não deu certo, uso ubuntu e xampp.
Alguem já passou por isso ?

Answer (score 0):

O `extension=php_intl.dll` não tem nada haver com Mcrypt API nem com mysql API, nos requisitos nem é mencionado:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.requirements.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.requirements.php

intl é um pacote para multi-idiomas e operações correlacionadas, segue as funções:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

### Mcrypt PHP exention missing!

Indica que sua aplicação precisa do Mcrypt:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php

Mas vale lembrar se esta usando PHP7.2.0+ o Mcrypt NÃO vai funcionar, ele foi removido nesta versão

### Mysql PHP exention missing!

Provavelmente se refere a versão da antiga API de mysql, o:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Esta API foi removida no php7.0+, pois para se comunicar com bancos mysql e mariadb as APIs melhoradas são a mysqli e PDO

### Resolução

Provavelmente tua aplicação é antiga, não tem como instalar sem usar uma versão mais antiga do PHP e realmente não é um problema sobre programação, é um problema sobre uso de um programa de terceiros, se fosse um script criado por ti simplesmente eu lhe diria:

> MCrypt esta descontinuado e foi removido no PHP7.2, migre suas
>   estruturas para [`sodium` (requer
>   php7.2)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) ou
>   [`openssl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php), vale lembrar que terá que refazer as estruturas, não
>   basta só trocar as funções.
>
> Mysql API (não me refiro ao banco, mas sim as funções antigas do PHP)
>   foi descontinuado, leia mais em:
>
> - [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)

---

**Reforçando**, o escopo do site é BEM DEFINIDO:

- um problema específico de programação
- um algoritmo de software
- ferramentas comuns entre programadores
- problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
- dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

Instalar aplicações de terceiros não é um problema pratico e nem bem definido sobre desenvolver softwares, também não é uma duvida teórica, logo não faz parte do escopo, só respondi porque achei necessário explicar a questão de estar usando uma aplicação antiga e que estas APIs foram descontinuadas e realmente não deveriam mais ser usadas pois elas tem problemas **de uso** e que nenhum dos problemas tem relação com `intl`, e realmente precisa rever de onde esta tirando estas informações incorretas.